# Is it OK to share your Facebook access token with others?

Tags: facebook-apps

I came across this particular app which is spreading virally among many Malaysian Facebook users:

`https://www.facebook.com/SpritzNetworks/app_190322544333196`

The app is asking users to copy paste a so called Sony Xperia Mobile token into their app.
Apparently the supposed mobile token is actually the users’ Facebook access token created for that particular Sony Xperia app.

*What are the repercussions of sharing the Facebook access token with the app this way?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You open yourself to access you most likely don't want to give. An access token is a way for a user to state that they are giving limited access for an application to see data.

Copy pasting the access_token means that you bypass the OAuth flow that prevents any hijacks of your account.

The access_token is in plain sight because the `redirect_uri` is set to http://facebook.com which doesn't handle the response.

> As the User access token is passed to your redirect_uri in the URL fragment, it therefore must be retrieved using some type of Javascript - this depends on the Javascript framework you want to use, some examples include querystring.parse in Node.js or jQuery BBQ.

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=token&display=popup&client_id=104018109673165&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/&response_type=token&perms=&scope=publish_stream,offline_access,user_photos,friends_photos,publish_actions,read_stream,email,user_status,user_activities,user_likes`

Gives the intruder (https://www.facebook.com/SpritzNetworks) access to the following

- publish_stream
- offline_access
- user_photos
- friends_photos
- publish_actions
- read_stream
- email
- user_status
- user_activities
- user_likes

Many shady pages, use Xperia app as a way to coax users into giving their access token

**Summary**: Don't give out your access_token, you aren't even supposed to know it exists in the first place.